# Which is better way to initialise Component in Yii2?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

I have created one component in Yii2 and extends it with `yii\base\Component`.

Now, I want to initialise the component that I have created which can be done in two ways

1. Using `new`:

   ```
   $sampleClass = new SampleClass();
   ```
2. Putting Component in config file:

   ```
   'sampleClass' => [
       'class' => 'app\components\SampleClass',
   ],
   ```

   and accessing it like `Yii::$app->sampleClass`.

What is difference between them and which is better way to initialise component?

Comment: You can use component like this way `use app\components\YourConponentName;`

Comment: instead of `new` you should use [`Yii::createObject()`](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-baseyii#createObject()-detail)  which although looks more complicated, it is more powerful because it is implemented on top of a [dependency injection container](https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/concept-di-container). other than that you can use either approach depending at how many places you need to call that component overall on the site, if several places, go for the config, if a single place, you can use `Yii::createObject()` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It mostly depends on your needs. Defining component in config and using it as `Yii::$app->sampleClass` creates one instance which can be easily configured at config level and shared across project. The perfect examples are DB connection or URL manager - usually you want to use the same instance of these components in multiple places, and you want to be able to easily configure them. Defining them in config and using as `Yii::$app->component` is natural choice in Yii (although it is bad practice overall and using `Yii::$app` as static service locator may be problematic in big applications).

Using `new` keyword or `Yii::createObject()` is better option if you don't want to share component or you want to pass it as dependency directly.